# No Sound with Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS after kernel Upgrade to linux 5.0

Tags: 18.04, sound, kernel

I am running Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS on a Dell laptop, I used UKUU to upgrade to a newer linux kernel (4.19) to resolve a previous sound problem.. 
I recently used UKUU to upgrade to the newest linux Kernel (5.0), and now after a susequent Ubuntu Software update I have NO sound...  After a reboot, Settings show "Dummy Output" for the only available Output.. 
If I run "pactl load-module module-detect" it returns 28, and then Settings shows "Built-in Analog Audio Stereo", but when I run the "Test Speakers" there is still no sound.

**Update March 6, 2019**
I notice on UKUU that I did NOT have linux kernel 4.20.14 installed, so I installed it and rebooted...   After rebooting, UKUU shows that I am running kernel 5.0, but I now have all the 4.20 kernels installed..
The sound now seems to be working better, if I run "pactl load-module module-detect" and then gnome-alsamixer after a reboot..

Comment: Do you happen to have timidity installed?

Comment: No I don't find timidity in the installed software..

Answer (score 0):

you should start with these three and then retest audio from speakers:

`$ sudo pactl load-module module-detect
$ sudo pactl load-module module-alsa-sink 
$ sudo pacmd set-default-sink $(pactl info | grep -i Sink | cut -d ':' -f2)`