# No sound from analog output after upgrade to Ubuntu 19.04

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, alsa, 19.04

So I've just updated to 19.04 and my integrated sound card stopped providing the analog output sink, here's pactl output:

```
~ $ pactl list short sinks
0   alsa_output.usb-Logitech_Logitech_Wireless_Headset_000D443A6F5C-00.analog-stereo    module-alsa-card.cs16le 2ch 48000Hz RUNNING
1   alsa_output.pci-0000_20_00.1.hdmi-stereo-extra2 module-alsa-card.c  s16le 2ch 44100Hz   SUSPENDED
2   alsa_output.pci-0000_20_00.1.hdmi-stereo-extra2.2   module-alsa-card.c  s16le 2ch 44100Hz   RUNNING
3   alsa_output.pci-0000_20_00.1.hdmi-stereo-extra2.3   module-alsa-card.c  s16le 2ch 44100Hz   SUSPENDED
```

I can still get the sound played on those sinks, but it's either wireless headphones or my monitor speakers, which are crap.

At some point I managed to get back the analog sink back, I think by re-installing alsa, but after reboot it disappeared. Running `acmd unload-module module-udev-detect && pacmd load-module module-udev-detect` doesn't seem to help either.

Any ideas?

Comment: I have the same problem as you :( , I've been looking for solutions with no success so far...

Answer (score 0):

I found this other question ( [No Sound with Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS after kernel Upgrade to linux 5.0](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1123349/no-sound-with-ubuntu-18-04-2-lts-after-kernel-upgrade-to-linux-5-0?rq=1) ), and its author provides a response that worked for me.

That was the output of running `pactl list short sinks` for me:

```
1   alsa_output.pci-0000_00_1f.3.iec958-stereo  module-alsa-card.c  s16le 2ch 44100Hz   IDLE
2   alsa_output.pci-0000_03_00.1.hdmi-stereo    module-alsa-card.c  s16le 2ch 44100Hz   SUSPENDED
```

Running the command `pactl load-module module-detect` worked for me, after its execution, the output of the first command is:

```
1   alsa_output.pci-0000_00_1f.3.iec958-stereo  module-alsa-card.c  s16le 2ch 44100Hz   IDLE
2   alsa_output.pci-0000_03_00.1.hdmi-stereo    module-alsa-card.c  s16le 2ch 44100Hz   SUSPENDED
3   alsa_output.2.analog-stereo module-alsa-sink.c  s16le 2ch 44100Hz   IDLE
```

I checked and the analog output is available again! :D .

**Important:** Notice the difference between your command (`pacmd load-module module-udev-detect`) and the proposed one (`pactl load-module module-detect`).

**EDIT:**

Running the following these commands in order (opposed to just executing the one I provided), makes the system to recognize even more output sinks (doing it in the inverse order may cause to replace sinks instead of adding on top without removing the previously added ones):

1. `pactl load-module module-alsa-sink`
2. `pactl load-module module-detect`

`pactl list short sinks`:

```
2   alsa_output.pci-0000_03_00.1.hdmi-stereo    module-alsa-card.c  s16le 2ch 44100Hz   SUSPENDED
3   alsa_output.2.analog-stereo module-alsa-sink.c  s16le 2ch 48000Hz   SUSPENDED
12  alsa_output.pci-0000_00_1f.3.analog-stereo  module-alsa-card.c  s16le 2ch 44100Hz   SUSPENDED
13  alsa_output.2.analog-stereo.2   module-alsa-sink.c  s16le 2ch 44100Hz   IDLE
```

Comment: u_u , it seems that the solution is temporary. And doesn't work always :s ...

Answer (score 0):

Check via two commands if there's a discrepancy between what aplay and what pulseaudio sees:

```
$ aplay -l

$ pacmd list-cards
```

If the second command does not include your analog output, but `aplay` lists it, then something is grabbing the analog outputs, preventing *pulseaudio* from using them. This [blog post](https://linux.goeszen.com/no-analog-sound-after-upgrade-to-ubuntu-19-04-heres-a-fix.html) suggests that **timidity** could grab the interface. Do you have timidity installed? Try stopping or removing it.